# Using Lists or Arrays to Efficiently Render and Update Entiteis within XNA 4.0 Refresh Enviroment

Tags: c#, windows-7, xna

As the title states, I was wondering what the most efficient method would be to run sets of classes setup something like this:

```
public enum MoveDirection { None, Up, Right, Left, Down};

abstract class Entity
{
    //For Power and Damage handling
    protected float health { get; set; }
    protected float energy { get; set; }
    protected float shield { get; set; }

    //For Leveling of Entities
    protected float experience { get; set; } //Not implemented
    protected int level { get; set; } //Not implemented

    //For Reclaimation purposes
    protected float data { get; set;}
    protected float matter { get; set; }

    //For Movement controls
    protected float maxSpeed { get; set; }
    protected float acceleration { get; set; } //Not implemented
    protected float angle { get; set; }
    protected Vector2 direction { get; set; }

    //Statistics monitoring
    protected int kills { get; set; }
    protected float damageRepaired { get; set; }
    protected float damageHealed { get; set; }
    protected int revives { get; set; }

    public virtual void MakeMove(MoveDirection moveDirection, float speed)
    {
        //Example method which is set by imput to move at a particular speed in a particular direction 
    }
}
```

This is an example of what I want to do. I have multiple classes inheriting from a base Entity class responsible for all moving, non-gridlocked objects within the game. I want the inheritors of the class to be able to access the Update() and Draw() functions in a way so they can accept input and draw their sprites while maintaining themselves in a list so I may create a limitless amount of them whenever I need, allow them to manage their own animations movement and such, but avoid creating tons of new KeyStates to minimize lag and keep my code clean.

Hopefully that's specific enough, I was not able to find an answer in search.

EDIT: Specifically, in single class games I want to have every class be able to check its own collision, input, rendering data without trying to for instance add a bullet into a list from a abstract class initialized by a player and then so. I'm coming from a single class XNA background with multiclass experience, but It seemed like there would be better methods to optimization the I was using.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track.  Your question isn't really clear though,  are you asking about how to use Lists to manage your entities?

Comment: Yes, I want to use a method which allows for as clean a game method as possible. Currently working on a large game, and having 80% of the code in Game1 is not working very well for collaboration either.